# Storing text using text-to-speech as an audio file (i.e. mp3)?

Tags: macos, audio, text-to-speech

I love listening to podcast-style audio while walking or in the car, and I love studying with the help of the text-to-speech feature in Mac OS Yosemite.  I want to download hour-long audio files to listen to in the car (I have already been accustomed enough to sometimes robotic-sounding tts voices).

How do I download text-to-speech to an audio file such as mp3?  I can "speak selected text when the key is pressed" and press option+esc, but shouldn't it be easy to just download the audio (without doing tedious stuff like recording tts audio playing)?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the `say` command in from the CLI (e.g. via “Terminal.app”). There is a detailed description in the man-page (type in `say`, right-click on the word and select “Open man page”). The `--output-file=` option does what you want.

There also is a number of apps that wraps this functionality in one way or another.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save text from "text-to-speech" into a file, then when you will have a text there, you should convert text file to audio file

More information on how to do that, you can read here:

```
https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/quickstart-protocol
```

How decoding files, you can read here:

```
https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/base64-decoding
```